# @Route - How to make sure doctrine also check parent entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I have some routes in my projets that are the result of a long parent/child relation.

The thing is that Symfony only search for the entity by it's ID. Ignoring all other parameters in the route.

For example, I have this route:

```
@Route("/projets/projet-{projet}/murs/mur-{mur}/obstacles/obstacle-{id}/", name="obstacle_edit")
editAction(Request $request, Obstacle $obstacle) {}
```

Here, `obstacle` is the entity I'm looking for.
`mur` is `$obstacle->getMur()`
and `projet` is `obstacle->getMur()->getProjet()`

Thus, my `form`tag is like this:

```
<form action="{{ path('obstacle_edit', { 'projet': obstacle.mur.projet.id, 'mur': obstacle.mur.id, 'id': obstacle.id }) }}" method="POST"></form
```

Yet, Doctrine run this query:

```
SELECT 
  t0.id AS id_1, 
  t0.nom AS nom_2, 
  t0.posx AS posx_3, 
  t0.posy AS posy_4, 
  t0.posz AS posz_5, 
  t0.dimx AS dimx_6, 
  t0.dimy AS dimy_7, 
  t0.dimz AS dimz_8, 
  t0.mur_id AS mur_id_9 
FROM 
  obstacle t0 
WHERE 
  t0.id = ?
```

Thus, ignoring the two other parameters in the route.

How can I make sure that other parameters won't be ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify how the entity is loaded by explicitly overriding the behavior using an annotation. See: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#fetch-via-an-expression

In your case it could look something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/projets/projet-{projet}/murs/mur-{mur}/obstacles/obstacle-{id}/", name="obstacle_edit")
 * @Entity("obstacle", expr="repository.findObstacleByProjectMurAndId(projet, mur, id)")
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Obstacle $obstacle) { ... }
```

The actual query logic you then put into this repository. Depending on what exactly you want this could be as easy as wrapping a `findBy(['mur' => $mur, 'projet' => $projet, 'id' => $id])` or a more sophisticated query.

Comment: I see, I was thinking of removing type from `Obstacle` parameter, add the two other, and also use a custom function. Works the same I guess. Thanks.